# QTreeView cell selected highlight resize

Tags: qt

Is there any way to customize focus rect size for QTreeView item? I have reviewed source code of paint() event of QStyledItemDelegate, and there is query for textRect inside them, but i not found the way to resize focus rect, it only paint a part of cell, containing text, i need to focus rect fill the entire cell rect. Any help?

cell focus rect example

[image]

Comment: mmm, explain yourself better, what is "cell focus rect"?

Comment: focus rect - is blue filled rectangle when item selected or mouse moves over item

Comment: This is typically dependent on the QStyle in use (windows/mac/fusion/style sheets). But it's not hard to re-implement a custom style for changing it. Or you could (probably) use CSS. Though I'm not sure from the picture if you mean focus or highlight area of selected item(s),or if that's text selected in editor widgets.

Comment: this is highlight area, not selected text, i want to highlight entire cell

Answer (score 0):

The default selection highlight depends on the current app style. On Windows it's partial, which is how other Windows apps behave.  With Fusion style (default on Linux) the selection highlight already covers the full item rectangle. Not sure on Mac.

Anyway, it's easily controlled with a style option which is set in the item delegate. All we need to do is set a flag, and luckily the style option init function is virtual. This is the same flag which is [set by default](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#3749) for some styles. Try this item delegate:

```cpp
class HighlightDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
  public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;

  protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
      QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
      option->showDecorationSelected = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: @subver55 You're welcome, glad it helped. Votes/acceptances are another good way to indicate your satisfaction...  :)   https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   Oh and welcome to SO!